# mysql import/drop very slow on pyshycal server

Tags: mysql

I have mysql installed on a physical server (name it Mysql A) and importing 1 MB .sql (from mysqldump) Magento file could take more than 5 minutes, and dropping database slow as well.

whereas importing the same .sql file into a mysql server that is installed on a VMware Virtual machine (name it Mysql B), it just takes 3 seconds.

the disk write/read test results on both physical and vm machine are equal.

Here is the settings on MySQL A (physical):
http://pastebin.com/3qAxCJxz

and MySQL B (vm):
http://pastebin.com/PqZePH8Z

both settings are default ubuntu mysql installations.

Any help on why it takes dramatically slower when importing/dropping database on my physical server? It's a HP Proliant ML-10 with 16GB of RAM, and  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1220 V2 @ 3.10GHz and the VM's host machine specs and performance has the same benchmark results as the server #A

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is important to know the load average in your MySQL server, in the VMWare server with Percona DB, the server (i assume) has no working tasks. but in the MySQL server you have some extra Work.
If your MySQL server is on a unix/linux server you can check your load average with the command top-i or simple use up time.

Another think you can check is how many connections do you have in your MySQL and your Connection Usage, the traffic, number of Queries, Query Caché,etc.

I hope this can help you to take a direction of way do you have this problem.s
Please update with more information if you still need more help.

Comment: both, the physical server and the VM instance are development machines they are idling.
The VM MySQL is oracle mysql, and the physical mysql is percona server but it doesn't matter, i tried oracle mysql and got same result, the vm mysql is still much faster.

Comment: here is the mysql status on the VM:
http://pastebin.com/TghWb239

And this one is on the physical server:
http://pastebin.com/HnyYen07

Comment: Hi , you are just looking into the MySQL environment, but i think you must check all the entire system, the uptime or top -i linux command, can help you to see if there is a problem outside of your MySQL servers